# Exterior power of representation and invariance

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, exterior-algebra

Let $G$ be a group, $(\rho,V)$ a finite dimensional real representation of $G$, and $W$ a subspace of $V$ of dimension $k$.

Assume that $\Lambda^k W$ is a $G$-invariant (and one dimensional) subspace of $\Lambda^k V$.

Does it mean that $W$ is $G$ invariant?

**Note:** $\Lambda^k$ stands for the $k$-th exterior power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes : assume that $g(w)\not\in W$ for some $w\in W$ and some $g\in G$. Take a decomposition $V = W\oplus W'$ (as vector spaces of course, not as $G$-modules) such that $g(w)\in W'$. Take a basis $(e_i)$ of $V$ that is adapted to this decomposition. You may assume that $e_1 = w$ and $g(e_1) = e_{k+1}$.

Then $e_{k+1}\wedge g(e_1\wedge \dots\wedge e_k) = e_{k+1}\wedge e_{k+1}\wedge (\dots) = 0$. But if we had $g(\Lambda^k W)\subset \Lambda^k W$ then $x:= g(e_1\wedge \dots\wedge e_k)$ would be a non-zero element of $\Lambda^k W$ so $e_{k+1}\wedge x$ would be non-zero in $\Lambda^{k+1}V$.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering: Is this a standard argument, or something you came up specifically to answer my question?

Comment: I came up with it, but the core of the argument est pretty standard : (pure) elements of $\Lambda^i V$ represent subspaces of dimension $i$ of $V$, so in a product $v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_i$ if one $v_j$ is not in a given subspace $W$, the product can't be in $\Lambda^i W$ (unless it's zero of course).

Comment: This argument has the following geometric interpretation: $G$ acts on the Grassmannian $Gr(k,V)$ of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V$, which is embedded $GL(V)$-equivariantly into $\mathbb P(\wedge^{k} V)$ by sending a subspace to its top wedge. Since this is an embedding and $G$ acts compatibly, $G$ fixes the subspace $W$ if and only if it fixes the top wedge power.